# Attach event handler to jQuery Extension

Tags: jquery

I want to attach an event handler for the focus event inside a jQuery Extension.
When the element (an input field) gets focused another function should be called.
I tried:

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.someExtension = function (options) {
        $(this).on("focus", function () {
            console.log("FOCUS");
        });
    }
})(window.jQuery);
```

and

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.someExtension = function (options) {
        $(this).focus(function () {
            console.log("FOCUS");
        });
    }
})(window.jQuery);
```

but none of them are working while I can do stuff like

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.someExtension = function (options) {
        $(this).attr("style", "color: red;");
    }
})(window.jQuery);
```

Putting all that together I have something like:
**HTML**
`<input id='input-field' />`
**JS (extension)**
see above
**JS for html page**
`$('#input-field').someExtension();`

Comment: Use an `id` or HTML5 attribute (dataset) to determine which input you working with may help

Comment: I have something like `$('#input').someExtension();` afterwards. Shouldn't that be enough? I want to notice when `#input` is focused so I would be surprised if I needed an `id`inside. This way I wouldn't need an extension at all would I?

Comment: I updated my question. Sorry if I was somehow unclear.

Comment: Does your execution of `someExtension()` appear after your markup for that input on the page?  It's not in a document ready so it would have to be.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/o7Lswqd4/3/  works fine if the command is after the markup.

Comment: That's strange. I would assume that none of my three examples work or at least no. 1 and no. 3. Do you have an idea why my third example (color change) works but the focus doesn't?

Comment: The focus works for me in the fiddle i linked.  In chrome and firefox.

Comment: I know. My question was why changing the text color this way works but not attaching an event handler. That's a bit confusing to me. Are there different prerequesites?

Comment: "but not attaching an event handler".  But it does work.  That's what I'm saying.  The fiddle shows that.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/o7Lswqd4/4/  all three work